# Approaches to modelling a robot head that was previous made using CSG in POV-Ray

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender but have done lots of CSG modelling in POV-Ray. It's just the way my mind works. :) The attached image shows a robot I made in POV-Ray years ago that I want to recreate in Blender so I can animate it. I realise this might take me some time.

[image: robot head side, front and under view]

I think I'll be able to figure out how to do most of it, but I'm having real problems trying to figure out how to approach modelling the head, particularly the chin. In POV-Ray the head is basically a cylinder with other cylinders cutting holes out of it, then with torii and spheres here and there to smooth the edges off. I could recreate that approach in Blender, I think, but is there a more elegant way?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried importing your model using Blender's POVRay importer?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that existed so I'll try that, but I want to get more into modelling directly in Blender as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 16 vertex cylinder, extrude inward, keep only 10 segments. Create a torus, 16 major segments, 6 minor segments, keep only 6 segments:

[image]

Join the 2 meshes:

[image]

Array on the Z axis, etc:

[image]